# CORS using fineuploader

Tags: .htaccess, cors, fine-uploader

I want to use `fineuploader` with  cross domain.
I get `Request header field Cache-Control is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` error.

My fineuploader config is:

```
        request: {
            endpoint: "http://api.polskieszlaki.local/4adm/zdjecia/fileupload",
        },
        cors: {
            expected: true,
        },
```

On my apache server in `.htaccess` I have

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

I have no firther ideas to make it work.

Comment: Just a note, you really shouldn't use `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` That is a security nightmare. Instead of using `*` specify what you would like to allow instead of allowing access to everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message cited in the question indicates you must change your `.htaccess` to have `Cache-Control` in the value set for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header, and because [the Fine Uploader docs](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/CORS.html#handling-xhr-cors-requests-server-side) indicate it sends the `X-Requested-With` header, then altogether you need:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
```

The [MDN docs for the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Headers) explain:

> The `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header is used in response to a preflight request to indicate which HTTP headers can be used when making the actual request.

Comment: Thanks that almost did work. I needed: `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Cache-Control, Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With"` Pleas edit anwser - I'll mark it correct

Comment: @piernik OK, updated (along with an explanation of why it’s necessary to also add 'X-Requested-With')